# C++: How to include Paillier.h in a header file

Tags: c++, cygwin

I have a C++ class *key_gen* that has some data members of type  *paillier_ prvkey_t*. The problem is that I cannot include paillier library (writen in c) in my header file say  *key_gen.h*.  But I can include it in my *key_gen.cpp* using

```
extern "C"{
#include<paillier.h>
}
```

I'm using cygwin to run my code, and I use command line as below:

```
g++ Key_Gen.cpp -L/cygdrive/c/cygwin/home/Win7/libpaillier -l:libpaillier.a -      
-lgmpxx -lgmp
```

As soon as I include the paillier header into my header file cygwin alerts when I run the code.

The error contains many lines e.g:

```
In file included from Key_Gen.h:13:0,
from Key_Gen.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/paillier.h:63:3: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef   
struct paillier_pubkey_t paillier_pubky_t’} paillier_pubkey_t;
                                            ^
```

Can someone tell me how to resolve the problem?

Comment: Does `paillier.h` have include guards?

Comment: @deviantfan No, it does'nt

Comment: Now you know what´s wrong. Add them, and everything is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you tell a C or C++ compiler to process a file, `foo.cpp`, the first stage of compilation is pre-processing which expands macros, substitutes defines and expands pre-processor directives such as `#include`.

In the early days, the preprocessor was a separate program, and it generated the output on the fly: the C compiler itself didn't know about `#include` and all it saw was a single stream of code.

Today, the preprocessor is usually an integral part of the compiler (gcc, MSVC, etc) but the single-stream effect for each source file you specify on the command line remains the same, and you can still access the compiler to generate the output of pre-processing as a single intermediate file so that you can see what translations went on (-E option to gcc/g++). So if you write:

```
// Foo.h
int foo;

// Bar.cpp
#include "Foo.h"
int bar;
#include "Foo.h"
```

What the *compiler* sees is a single contiguous stream:

```
/* "Bar.cpp" from command line */
// Bar.cpp
/* "Foo.h" from Bar.cpp:2 */
int foo;
/* end "Foo.h" */
int bar;
/* "Foo.h" from Bar.cpp:4 */
int foo;
/* end "Foo.h" */
/* end "Bar.cpp" */
```

- The compilation stage doesn't know about `#include`,
- The pre-processor doesn't do de-duplication of `#include`s by default, so multiple includes produce duplication.

If you want to add `paillier.h` to your own `.h` file you will need to prevent this duplication. There are two common ways to do this.

1. pragma guard

At the start of the .h file use the pre-processor directive #pragma, understood by both the GNU C and C++ compilers:

```
#pragma once
```

Pro: The pre-processor detects duplication at the `#include` statement and so doesn't have to re-read the file.
Con: Most compilers use the include file's path to do this, so

```
#include "../include/foo.h"
#include "foo.h"
```

might both reference the same file but on some compilers will still produce duplication.

2. #ifndef guard

At the start of the .h file check for the definition of a unique pre-processor symbol and, if not defined, define it

```
#ifndef PAILLIER_H
#define PAILLIER_H
```

and at the very end of the file

```
#endif // PAILLIER_H  (comment is optional)
```

Pro: De-duplicates regardless of path.
Con: Can cause problems if your guard name isn't unique enough (I worked on a project where someone used 'HEADER' in more than one header file)
Con: The pre-processor still has to read the entire header file to find the #endif.

**In summary**

You may also want to add the following to make your file work when included from both C and C++

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// all your symbols etc here

#ifdef __cplusplus
}; // extern "C"
#endif
```

This is going to make your header file look something like this:

```
#ifndef PAILLIER_H
#define PAILLIER_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// original code here
...
// end original code

#ifdef __cplusplus
}; // extern "C"
#endif

#endif // PAILLIER_H
```

or

```
#pragma once

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// original code here
...
// end original code

#ifdef __cplusplus
}; // extern "C"
#endif
```

--- Edit ---

There's no reason you can't use both

```
#pragma once
#ifndef MYPROJECT_SOMETHING_H
...
#endif
```

This way if #pragma fails you for path reasons, you're still covered.